# How to add an argument to a function in a python .bat file

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, shell, batch-file

I have a file with a function and a file that calls the functions. Finally, I run .bat
I don't know how I can add an argument when calling the .bat file. So that the argument was added to the function as below.

file_with_func.py

```
def some_func(val):
    print(val)
```

run_bat.py

```
from bin.file_with_func import some_func

some_func(val)
```

myBat.bat

```
set basePath=%cd%
cd %~dp0
cd ..
python manage.py shell < bin/run_bat.py
cd %basePath%
```

Now I would like to run .bat like this.

```
\bin>.\myBat.bat "mystring"
```

**Or after starting, get options to choose from, e.g.**

```
\bin>.\myBat.bat

>>> Choose 1 or 2
>>> 1
```

**And then the function returns**
`"You chose 1"`

Comment: I use these commands in *pyCharm*, and the function with no arguments works normally. But adding to `.bat %1` doesn't change anything. Shell generates a message that there are no such `"flags"`

Answer (score 0):

You can run it using arguments as input using the `sys` module

When in you script you call

```
python test.py var1
```

Inside test.py in the first lines you must have

```
import sys
print(sys.argv[0]) # prints test
print(sys.argv[1]) # prints var1
```

Comment: It doesn't save me. Since I'm using Django and I don't use cmd but in pyCharm terminal where I have django I run .bat

Answer (score 0):

In

```
\bin>.\myBat.bat "mystring"
```

"mystring" is a paramter. So, we need to tell myBat.bat where to use the parameter.

Try:
myBat.bat

```
set basePath=%cd%
cd %~dp0
cd ..
python manage.py shell < bin/run_bat.py %1
cd %basePath%
```

%1 represents the one and only parameter.

Comment: when i use `python manage.py shell < bin\run_bat.py %1`
and `\bin>.\myBat.bat "mystring"` I have shell chimney 
`manage.py shell [-h] [--no-startup] [-i {ipython,bpython,python}] [-c COMMAND] [--version] [-v {0,1,2,3}] [--settings SETTINGS] [--pythonpath PYTHONPATH] [--traceback]
                       [--no-color] [--force-color]`